# Ensure web app access from a single computer per user

Tags: php

I have developed a web application in PHP for a client. The client is now renting out access to the system to another company on a per user basis.

Is there a way to prevent the secondary company to use a single login and give it to 20 people to use at the same time? I know one can get the IP address of the client machine that is being logged in from, but this is obviously not very reliable method. The answer probably lies in a combination of cookies and tracking things in a database, but my brain gets a bit stuck thinking on how to implement a strategy here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a unique session ID when a user logs in and store that in the DB. Add something to the session authentication code (run on all page visits) that checks that the user's session ID is equal to the one in the DB and if not, log them out. Then your web app will be accessible by only one user at a time.

To be completely honest though, can't you raise this issue with your client?

Comment: And don't forget to issue a warning (possibly related to locking etc), otherwise people will think that your app is buggy :)

Comment: @battal - Definitely. "Never surprise the user" would have to be one of the top 10 rules of application development, followed by "Explain surprising things when they do happen".

Comment: Am I wrong, or you also need to delete the [userID, sessionID] record stored in the Db when the user logs out? How to prevent "orphans" records in the case that a user turn off the pc or the browser without logging out?

Answer (score 2):

No way to tell if the login is shared among 20 people. You can restrict access by blocking simultaneous usage thru session cookies.

Most of all, protect yourself with a published **Terms and Conditions** document. Violation of which - revokes any standing agreement/contract. And sue them if you can provide evidence (logs) that they violated it.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you bind one user to one session. In that way you can generate a warning screen if somebody uses the same login with another session. You can then let the user choose to close the other session.

In that way you can make sure two users are not using the system at the same time. It's a bit like a software program you have installed on a computer: multiple users can use it, but only one at a time. This is probably fine.

If you don't want that, you should try to bind the login more firmly to the user: make sure he logs in with a personal e-mail address, and he gets notifications (if applicable) via e-mail. Also let the user set personal configurations. In that way you create **extra value** for users to have their own account.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a login you have authentication, and you write any user id in session, make sure that only one session with this id created, if the session already exists throw error message.

The only problem you will have in case and user did not logout properly, instead of it pressing x button on browser then he will not be able to login till session s not expired.